# Corrupted files after drag/drop upload into outlook folders

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange-2013

I'm having an issue with outlook when i drag and drop attachments into a folder.  The problems appear for a day or 2 then goes away. It's happening with multiple users on multiple computers all running Windows 10, but with different versions of Outlook. We're hosting our own Exchange 2013 instance on-premise.

If they receive an email with an attachment, PDF, TXT, JPG doesn't matter. We can view that attachment without any problem inside outlook.

We can drag/drop and download this attachment to local disk, it can open fine from the local drive.

Now if we drag/drop the same file back into any folder or subfolder in outlook it immediately becomes corrupt, i can't preview it in outlook and i can't re-download it again. It becomes a corrupt object in the outlook folder. I can delete it without any issue.

Tried the following so far with no resolution

- Rebooted Server
- moved affected user/mailbox to a new EDB on server
- removed/reinstall outlook on desktop
- updated outlook to the latest version
- installed an older outlook 2013 version
- the folder in outlook does not matter
- disabled all AV software

Any other suggestions ?

Thank you

Comment: What is the purpose of dragging a file in to an Outlook folder? I honestly didn’t know that was possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a profile issue, clear appdata for outlook local and roaming on the affected users profile. This will cause the users to re-download their in-boxes and off-line contacts so minor inconvenience but it'll resolve your problem.

Comment: This is only alluding to the symptom and NOT how to prevent or the rationale it created itself, OR why it seemingly disappears at random.

Comment: @linuxdev2013 - good point but the answer provided was correct. DO you have any suggestions on how to prevent the issue or how to even track the cause of the issue ?